# How to get notified as soon as new data gets inserted in azure table storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure Table Storage where data is expected to be inserted from a web service.

My App (ASP.Net MVC , VS 2017) has SignalR implemented to receive any changed data from Azure Table Storage.

**My Problem**

After a new data arrives in Table Storage, only if I refresh a browser, the latest data automatically gets reflected in any other opened browsers - either in same or different computer systems.It doesn't automatically display the changed value in any opened browser as soon new data gets into Table Storage.
I guess this may be because when I refresh the browser, as per my code it gets the data from Table and SignalR fires to send the data to other clients.

So there is a gap here in sending notification from the Table whenever new data arrives.

**My Query**

1. What is that I am missing here - it doesn't show the latest data on the browser automatically?
2. Or is it that Table Storage do not have any notification mechanism to notify new-data-arrived?
   If so what should be done receive notification whenever a new data arrives into Azure Table Storage?

My Action Method

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = SignalRepository.LatestSignalCollection();// Connects with Azure to fetch the latest 5 records
        return View(model);

    }
```

My SignalR Hub Code

```
public SignalHub()
    {
        SignalRepository.SignalSubscriber();
        var signalData = SignalRepository.LatestSignalCollection(); //LatestSignalCollection() ===>  Connects with Azure to fetch the latest 5 records
        GetAllClients().All.SendSignalData(signalData);

    }
```

My js file - SignalR Connect code

```
var signalHub = $.connection.signalHub; //alert("ACCC");
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
// Start the hub
$.connection.hub.start();
signalHub.client.SendSignalData = function (signalData) {
     updateSignalData(signalData);// updates the elements in Index.cshtml
}
```

Comment: Could you place a trigger in your web service to initiate the update for you?

Comment: I didn't get you.
Do you mean to call the Index() ActionMethod after it gets inserted via Web Service?

Comment: is there a web service responsible for making the inserts and updates to the Azure Table storage?  I would need to know more about the whole of the problem otherwise I am just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you’d like to push notification to all connected clients when new data that inserted from a web service arrives into your Azure Table storage. I suggest that you could invoke your hub method to broadcast new data to all connected clients after you execute the code to insert the data into Azure Table storage.

```
var hub = new HubConnection("http://xxx/signalr/hubs");

var proxy = hub.CreateHubProxy("{HubName}");
hub.Start().Wait();

//invoke hub method
proxy.Invoke("{HubMethod}", "{partitionkey&rowkey}");
```

In your hub method, you will get the **partition key** and **row key** of the latest data, and then you can retrieve the entity based on partition key and row key, and call JavaScript side function `SendSignalData` to update web page elements.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this? I am confused on how to send partitionKey & rowKey from proxy.Invoke.  I already have a connection started ($.connection.hub.start();). Now where should these (below) take place ====> var hub = new HubConnection("http://xxx/signalr/hubs");    ====> var proxy = ...     =======> proxy.Invoke("{HubMethod}", "{partitionkey&rowkey}");

Comment: ``where should these (below) take place`` It seems that you insert data in a web service, you could invoke hub method and pass parameters (pk and rk) after the code that you used to do inserting data in your web service.

Comment: The code you have given above are JavaScript  `proxy.Invoke("{HubMethod}", "{partitionkey&rowkey}");` ===> Can you please help me with a code snippet to invoke the Hub Method from Webservice? Should I make a reference of Hub class in WebService? Won't it turn as a circular reference? I am confused on how to do this. If you can give me code snippet it sure would help me.

Comment: It is not JavaScript code. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170373/signalr-broadcasting-over-a-hub-in-another-project-from-outside-of-a-hub) discussed how to broadcast over a Hub in another project from outside of a Hub class, please refer to it.

Comment: Hi @jAntoni ,are you able to execute hub method in another project from outside of hub class now?

Comment: The code you have suggested seems to be promising and the logic you have given here, sure would address my problem I feel.
Just held up with some thing else, will be continuing it in a day - I am going to try this if it works out for me.
Thanks Fred, I will update you  in a day or two.

Comment: Since my Webservice is within my webapp, from your replies above I tried to make a call to the `SignalRSubscribe` in the webMethod after the `callTo_Insert_to_Table_Storage` and it did the work for me. **Thanks**. Without the above replies\explanation this wouldn't have clicked me.