# Is it possible to generate SignalR hubs on a centralised server from a different app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I have multiple Web apps using SignalR, generating different local hubs.

I was wondering, would it be possible to give the server URL to the application **A** so it generates the local SignalR hubs directly on the centralised server, so then the application **B** could reference the generated hubs directly from the server, instead of creating a proxy on the application **B** to listen to the the application **A** broadcast?

```
public class ApplicationA : Hub //https://applicationAurl
{
    public void SendFromApplicationA(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }
}


public class ApplicationB : Hub //https://applicationBurl
{
    public void SendFromApplicationB(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

So if these hubs were created on the server instead of the  mother app, the application **C** should be able to listen to both on the client side, like something below.

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://centralisedserver/signarl";
$.connection.hub.start();

var SendFromApplicationAHub= $.connection.applicationA;
SendFromApplicationAHub.client.SendFromApplicationA = function () {//do something}

var SendFromApplicationBHub= $.connection.applicationB;
SendFromApplicationBHub.client.SendFromApplicationB = function () {//do something}
```

Comment: Perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170373/signalr-broadcasting-over-a-hub-in-another-project-from-outside-of-a-hub

Comment: @danish Not really the same thing I'm trying to do, that is sort of a proxy generation question. I'm trying to merge all hubs from different apps and have a single end point for all of them.

Comment: Ah ok, I have not done anything like that so can't really help. Probably will attempt to do. I did found this one the web. Don't know if this is what you need. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/898992/RESTful-SignalR-Service